# How to resolve [Linker Error] Unresolved external in Borland C++ builder 6

Tags: c++, linker, c++builder-6

I downloaded [DeltaCopy](http://www.aboutmyip.com/AboutMyXApp/DeltaCopy.jsp) source code and tried to compile it using Borland C++ builder 6.0.

The downloaded code has three projects.I tried to build one named as "deltaS" and got runtime error as :

> Linker Error] Unresolved external 'TConsoleRunner :: Run (System ::
>   AnsiString, _STL :: vector <_STL :: basic_string , _STL :: allocator > _STL :: allocator <_STL
>   :: basic_string , _STL :: allocator
>    >>> *, void *) 'referenced from C: \ DeltaCopy \
>   MAINFORMSERVER.OBJ

I am completely new to C++ environment of Borland and don't know how to resolve it.But by reading the message I assume there is some header file most probably STL library which was not linked at runtime.
If anyone has faced this issue then please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to one of your .cpp files:

```
#pragma comment(lib, "libcpmt.lib")
```

It tells the linker to link to `libcpmt.lib` so any references to its code can be resolved.

Alternatively, you can add the `libcpmt.lib` file itself to your project, which has the same effect.

Comment: could you elaborate your answer....i did not understand..

Comment: I did the above and got `[Linker Fatal Error] Fatal: Unable to open file 'LIBCPMT.LIB'` .Now wht to do???